# "DataNucleus Enhancer completed with an error"

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

Am trying to create a model class to store an Entity in `Google App Engine` using Eclipse.But when i save my work i get the error message:

> org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager initialiseFileMetaDataForUse.
>   SEVERE: Class "com.packagename.classname" has been specified with an object-id class javax.jdo.identity.StringIdentity yet no fields have been identified as primary key fields. Please notate using the "primary-key" tag against the fields that should be considered part of the primary key.

If my understanding of JPA is correct, i do not need a `primary-key` for an entity since i already have a `@Id` tag.Here is my class.

```
@Entity
  public class MyCLassName {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private static String userName;

private static String location;
private static Date dateOfBirth;
private static int age;
private static String gender;
private static String teamName;
private static int weight;





//Constructor with arguments
public MyClassName(String userName, String location, String gender, int age, Date DOB, int weight) {
    MyClassName.userName = userName;
    MyClassName.location = location;
    MyClassName.gender = gender;
    MyClassName.age=age;
    MyClassName = DOB;
    MyClassName.weight = weight;

}
//setter methods
public static void setUserName(String userName) {
    MyClassName.userName = userName;
}

public static void setLocation(String location) {
    MyClassName.location = location;
}

public static void setGender(String gender) {
    MyClassName.gender = gender;
}

public static void setAge(int age) {
    MyClassName.age = age;
}

public static void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
    MyClassName.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

public static void setWeight(int weight) {
     MyClassName.weight = weight;
}

//getter methods
public static String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public static int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public static String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public static String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public static String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public static Date getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public static int getAge() {
    return age;
}

    }
```

What exactly am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of JPA is partially correct.  You do not need to assign the primary key because you have used the @Id and @GeneratedValue annotation.  The JPA implementation will automatically generate the primary key value as a long integer.  However it still needs a field in which to store this ID value.  It is trying to do that in userName.  See [Java Tutorial ID Generation Type: IDENTITY](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/IDGenerationTypeIDENTITY.htm) for example.

Comment: Okay, now i created a variable `id` of type `int` and replaced it with `username` and the error stops, does this mean a `String` cannot be a primary key? This is contrary to what i have learned about JPA so far

Comment: You are correct about String generally being a valid primary key.  In your code it is the GenerationType.IDENTITY that is incompatible with String.  IDENTTY is usually implemented as a long integer, not a String.  If you do prefer to have a String username as primary key, then do not use the @GeneratedValue annotation, but rather assign unique usernames from your own code.